# aiohttp replaces %3A with :

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

My API server wants the URL to have %3A which I generate using urllib parse quote. However when I pass the URL to aiohtttp it replaces it with ':' . How to avoid this ?

Example : `END POINT = http://server/item_url/http%3A//<path_to_item>`

when i pass this url to aiohttp `session.post(END_POINT, data)` my request fails which when i debug found out that `http%3A//` has become `http://`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh i have expanded my question

Comment: `post` can also take the url as a [`yarl.URL`](https://yarl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#yarl.URL) object.  Could you try creating one of those objects and using it as your url?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes , that's the right solution to the problem . I did more search on this topic and came across : https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2188 , where they talk about the same problem and the solution. Thanks !